# file link doesn't work

Tags: html, file, hyperlink

I can't achieve working linking between my index.html and main.css/img.pgn files.

File tree: HTML file(not working): /home/user/Desktop/vswd/index.html
           CSS file: /home/user/Desktop/vswd/en/css/main.css
           IMG file: /home/user/Desktop/vswd/en/img/img.png

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../en/css/main.css"/>  doesn't work

<img class="img" src="../en/img/img.png"> doesn't work
```

BUT

if I move the file one folder below linking work fine.

File tree: HTML file(not working): /home.user/Desktop/vswd/en/index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css"/>  work fine

<img class="img" src="../img/img.png"> work fine
```

I tried everything but didn't find a solution.

Comment: Please accept an answer (a.k.a. turn the check mark green) if a correct one has been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `index.html` and `en/` are in the `vswd` directory, so you don't need to go up a directory using `../`. Instead, use `./`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./en/css/main.css"/>
<img class="img" src="./en/img/img.png">
```

Comment: @VáclavStummer, If that solves the problem then mark as solved https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135826